# Jquery draggable echo the dropped div class id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to echo the div id where I drop the draggable cube.

Any clue on how to track where the div is drop?
I read the position from jquery but did not figure it out.

Here is my code for this:

```js
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var drop_p = $(this).offset();
        var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
        var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left + 1;
        var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top + 1;

        ui.draggable.animate({
            top: '+=' + top_end,
            left: '+=' + left_end
        });
    }
});

$('.boxArt').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    stack: ".boxArt"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(this.id)// this.id will give the `.drop` id to which the element was dropped
        var drop_p = $(this).offset();
        var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
        var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left + 1;
        var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top + 1;

        ui.draggable.animate({
            top: '+=' + top_end,
            left: '+=' + left_end
        });
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C5Grc/)